# Does Microsoft ReportViewer require special handling to Dispose correctly?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I've spent the last day tracking down what seems to be a memory leak issue in my code, and believe I have finally pinned down the culprit - the report generation. In order to see where the problem lies I created an empty solution, with just a button on a blank form, linked to this event:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer temp = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();
            temp.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Opening this form and clicking the button, I watch Windows Task Manager and I can see the Memory begin climbing, along with the USER Objects, which in a matter of a minutes hits the cap of 10,000 and causes a WIN32Exception: Unable to create handle.

Debugging it line by line, you can see on creation the USER Objects goes up by 7, and then on Dispose it goes down by only 5.

I have tried `temp.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain()` based on other issues people were having, I've also tried the same loop but with `using` around the report viewer, to see if it behaved differently - it didn't.

My question is, is there any special handling around the ReportViewer that I am missing?

(FYI, I'm working on .NET Framework 4 with Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms version 10)

Comment: No repro on version 11 and 12, you'll need to update.

Comment: In this code example memory leak in version 12 don't exists.

Comment: But problem realy exists in that local rdlc report.